# Amount of mathematical knowledge required for starting Ph.D. in pure mathematics

Tags: soft-question, education, advice, career-development

How much mathematics should one know before starting a Ph.D. program in pure mathematics? For example what topics one must understand well to pursue a Ph.D. in Number Theory?

Comment: If you are in Bordeaux, there are professors there who can help you with this.

Comment: @Deane I am not in Bordeaux anymore :(

Comment: This is going to depend a *lot* on the country and the program (and possibly the advisor).

Comment: "Number theory" is a broad topic as it is. For instance, one could go down different routes of analytic or algebraic number theory. You really need to figure out a specialty before asking how to do well in such a broad subject because it'd be hard to recommend anything beyond the basic classes every math major should have (e.g. set theory, real/complex analysis, rudimentary abstract algebra), plus a few dashes of whatever is vaguely relevant (e.g. elementary number theory, programming). And then you have considerations of ideal career path, school, program, etc., to consider...

Comment: @Aphelli Let's say we are talking about any graduate program at US universities.

Comment: Well you ought to at least know all the basics from an undergrad, i.e. real/complex analysis, abstract algebra, general topology, some functional analysis, and definitely a number theory class in your case! You should also (obviously) have a strong understanding of mathematical logic. I guess, in short, my answer is: A LOT! Not to mention you should have a lot of specialized knowledge specific to your research topic...

Comment: @PrincessEev Thanks for your comments. I agree that Number Theory is indeed a broad topic. Even though if I narrow it down to Diophantine equations, is it still broad or does it help?

Comment: I don’t understand the US system very well, but my guess would be to check the most advanced undergrad classes around the theme that you want to study and understand their contents…

Comment: I believe that the French M2 has a “better” (or at least more advanced) level than a typical US PhD admission. That’s because native PhD candidates only had four years of undergrad, while the French M2 is the fifth year after high school graduation. Of course, I may be wildly wrong for a variety of reasons. But I’d be surprised if typical PhD candidates could tell what a proper morphism of schemes is, or what class field theory is (both of which are covered in some of the “non-advanced” ALGANT classes in Bordeaux at level M2).

Comment: 10 % 
kidding , ask your advisors prof etc

Comment: If you’ve already been admitted into a PhD program, I suggest you relax for now. Youll find out what you need to know after you start. The first priority will be passing the qualifying exams.

Comment: This reminds me of the old anecdote, where when Schrödinger (?), was asked  “How much math does a theoretical physicist need?” answered: “More.” Seriously, US grad schools vary considerably in how much they expect, and even within one, how much new grad students actually have.